# Ubuntu create swap automatically even I have no swap partition setup?

Tags: swap, 20.10

I was preparing the servers for setup a Kubernetes cluster, based on the official document, `You MUST disable swap in order for the kubelet to work properly` [Ref here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/).

So I did not create a swap partition to begin with. (GPT - LVM - /boot & /)
[image]

After the installation done, I check the status of the swap, there it is "SWAP 2G"

[image]

But `lsblk` still shows no swap

[image]

So I guess the swap in OS and the swap on disk are different?

Comment: The swap you’re seeing is for a swap *file* rather than a partition. It’s there to make sure the system doesn’t completely fall over if all the RAM is consumed 

Comment: so kubernetes wants to disable this "swap file" rather than a partition ?

Comment: You can disable it with `sudo swapoff -a` - for a permanent disable, you could comment it out of `/etc/fstab`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since several versions, the Ubuntu installer by default creates a swap file rather than a dedicated swap partition. You will find this swapfile announced in the system configuration file `/etc/fstab` with an entry similar to:

```
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

To permanently disable that swap space, you need to edit the file `/etc/fstab` (as administrator, e.g. `sudoedit /etc/fstab`) and disable that line. A safe way is to put a comment mark `#` in front of the line. That way, you could reinstate the swap space easily by removing the comment again. You may also choose to delete that line.

It is not a bad idea to have swap space. Rather than getting rid of swap, you could opt to disable swap only when you are planning to run that particular application. Swap can temporarily be turned off with

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

You can re-enable all swap with

```
sudo swapon -a
```

Swap will automatically be reinstated after rebooting if swap is announced in `/etc/fstab`.